# Problem in Printing in JFrame with JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

```
I want to print a String in a JLabel
```

I used this code for that but it's not printing please where's it wrong
The code is to display the day in the JFrame via JLabel
Firstly i made a string for day then i got the Calendar and used it to get DAY_OF_WEEK
and by usind if else i frint the date but it is not printing why i don't know please correct it

```
package com.lalankumar.widget;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.*;

    public class RWidget extends JFrame{
    
        String wday;
        int d;
        public RWidget() {
            
             Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            d= c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
          Font dayFont = new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 25);        
           Font routine = new Font("Courier", Font.ITALIC, 15);                
            setUndecorated(true);
            setLocation(1168,0);
            setSize(200,200);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
             setVisible(true);
            setBackground(new Color(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,0.1f));
                
                if(d==2) {
                    wday="Monday";                       
                } else if(d==3) {
                     wday="Tuesday";                         
                } else if(d==4) {
                    wday="Wednesday";                       
                } else if(d==5) {
                    wday="Thursday";                        
                } else if(d==6) {
                    wday="Friday";                      
                } else if(d==7) {
                    wday="Saturday";                        
                } else {
                    wday="Sunday";                      
                }
                JLabel dayl= new JLabel(wday);                  
                dayl.setFont(dayFont);                  
                
        }           
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new RWidget();   
        }
          }
```

Please Help fast

Whole code is given above
Please check where it's wrong or why it is not working.

Comment: JLabel dayl= new JLabel(wday); this just creates a new label, it doesn't add it to the JFrame. You should create it at the start of your application, add it to your JFrame, and at that point, just use the setText(wday);

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new JLabel, to which you are setting the text, but you are not adding it to your JFrame.

I'll step by step simplify your code a bit, and add some comments on what the changes do:

```
package com.lalankumar.widget;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.*;

    public class RWidget extends JFrame{
    
        // String wday; we don't need this variable
        // int d; this can be a local variable
        public RWidget() {
            
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int d= c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
            Font dayFont = new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 25);        
            Font routine = new Font("Courier", Font.ITALIC, 15);
            JLabel text = new JLabel(""); // create a new JLabel, and set the font
            text.setFont(dayFont);
            this.add(text); // add the new Label to the JFrame
            // if you add a String to the constructor, you'll see that immediately on the JFrame
            
            setUndecorated(true);
            setLocation(1168,0);
            setSize(200,200);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setVisible(true);
            // comment this, to make the jFrame easier to see
            // setBackground(new Color(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,0.1f));
                // replace the conditions by a switch to improve readability
                switch(d) {
                   case 2: text.setText("Monday"); break;
                   case 3: text.setText("Tuesday"); break;
                   case 4: text.setText("Wednesday"); break;
                   case 5: text.setText("Thursday"); break;
                   case 6: text.setText("Friday"); break;
                   case 7: text.setText("Saturday"); break;
                   default: text.setText("Sunday");
                }
                // don't create a new JLabel
                // JLabel dayl= new JLabel(wday);                  
                // dayl.setFont(dayFont);                  
                
        }           
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new RWidget();   
        }
          }
```

What you also can do, instead of the switch:

```
String[] days = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
text.setText(days[d-1]);
```